# Are there multiple ways to write some summations? (Example below)

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functions, summation, fractions

Consider the series

$0+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{5}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{5}{7} +  ...$

Are there multiple ways to write this in sigma notation? For example:

A) $\sum_{k=0}^{infinity} \frac{k}{k+2}$

B) $\sum_{k=1}^{infinity} \frac{k-1}{k+1}$

Are both equivalent? Or is one better than the other - I came up with the first one whereas as the second one is the given answer. Is there a reason why this is?

Comment: Is the uppercase $K$ meant to be a lowercase $k$?

Comment: The two aren't equivalent.  The top one ends with $\frac n{n+2}$ and the bottom one ends with $\frac {n-1}{n+1}$.  To be sure, the initial expression doesn't refer to $n$ at all, so I'd have assumed it went on forever.

Comment: If the answer is $\mathbf{YES}$ to the question asked by marcelgoh in the first comment, then the answer given by lulu in the second comment is correct. I want to add the followings. (A) has $n+1$ terms including the first term, which is zero, while (B) has only $n$ terms including the first term, which is also zero. The equality given below holds. $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k}{k+2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k-1}{k+1} + \frac{n}{n+1}$$

Comment: Thanks everyone - apologies, it was meant to read 'infinity' not 'n' !!

Comment: Does that change your answers?

Answer (score 1):

They are not both equivalent since $A)$ ends at $\frac{n}{n+2}$ while $B)$ ends at $\frac{n-1}{n+1}$. So $A)$ has one extra term.

Making the change of index of summation $k'=k+1$, the limits at $k=0$ and $k=n$ become $k'=1$ and $k'=n+1$ respectively. Thus we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k}{k+2}=\sum_{k'=1}^{n+1}\frac{k'-1}{k'-1+2}=\sum_{k'=1}^{n+1}\frac{k'-1}{k'+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k-1}{k+1}$$
since $k'$ is a variable.

This is not unique. Choosing the index of summation $k'= k+j$, for $j\in\mathbb Z$,  we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k}{k+2}=\sum_{k'=j}^{n+j}\frac{k'-j}{k'-j+2}=\sum_{k=j}^{n+j}\frac{k-j}{k-j+2}$$

In the above case we have $j=1$.

Comment: Sorry Ares - it wasn't meant to say n - it was meant to read 'infinity' - does your answer still hold true?

Comment: If $n$ goes to $\infty$, then it is true that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k+2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k-1}{k+1}.$$

Comment: The answer above still holds. Note that the start of the summation changes for different $j$. You can compute the first few terms and see that they are in fact the same.